# Creating the three level dependent drop-down list with array of objects using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am creating three level drop-down list from the array of objects which I fetched from the API(dynamic data). I tried removing the duplicate values from ssmlGender(Voice gender) field and did try different methods. But, couldn't fetch the right data.

In first drop-down list, I am displaying the gender: "Female" and "Male" from "ssmlGender" field. When the user selects the male or female in the first drop-down list, the second drop-down list must be populated with "languageCodes" available for the particular gender. When the language code is selected, the "name" field which has the both the selected gender and languageCodes should be displayed.

Sample Array:

```
0: {languageCodes: Array(1), name: "es-ES-Standard-A", ssmlGender: "FEMALE", naturalSampleRateHertz: 24000}
1:
{languageCodes: Array(1), name: "it-IT-Standard-A", ssmlGender: "FEMALE", naturalSampleRateHertz: 24000}
2:
{languageCodes: Array(1), name: "ja-JP-Standard-A", ssmlGender: "FEMALE", naturalSampleRateHertz: 22050}
3:
{languageCodes: Array(1), name: "ko-KR-Standard-A", ssmlGender: "FEMALE", naturalSampleRateHertz: 22050}
8:{languageCodes: Array(1), name: "en-US-Wavenet-D", ssmlGender: "MALE", naturalSampleRateHertz: 24000}
9:
{languageCodes: Array(1), name: "en-US-Wavenet-A", ssmlGender: "MALE", naturalSampleRateHertz: 24000}
10:
{languageCodes: Array(1), name: "en-US-Wavenet-B", ssmlGender: "MALE", naturalSampleRateHertz: 24000}
11:
{languageCodes: Array(1), name: "en-US-Wavenet-C", ssmlGender: "FEMALE", naturalSampleRateHertz: 24000}
12:
{languageCodes: Array(1), name: "en-US-Wavenet-E", ssmlGender: "FEMALE", naturalSampleRateHertz: 24000}
13:
{languageCodes: Array(1), name: "en-US-Wavenet-F", ssmlGender: "FEMALE", naturalSampleRateHertz: 24000}
14:
{languageCodes: Array(1), name: "en-GB-Standard-A", ssmlGender: "FEMALE", naturalSampleRateHertz: 24000}
15:
{languageCodes: Array(1), name: "en-GB-Standard-B", ssmlGender: "MALE", naturalSampleRateHertz: 24000}
```

When we click on the particular array, it will display the data as given in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFYGm.jpg

My HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
                <label>Voice Gender</label>
                <div class="input-field col s12">                    
                    <select id="gender">
                            <option value="" selected>Choose your option</option>                                                     
                            </select>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <label>Voice Language</label>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <select id="languages">
                        <option value="" selected>Choose your languages</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="row">
                <label>Voice Name</label>
                <div class="input-field col s12">                    
                    <select id="entries">
                            <option value="" selected>Choose your option</option>                           
                            </select>
                </div>
        </div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
for(var i=0;i<response.result.voices.length;i++){
         var values= response.result.voices;

            //To remove the duplicate value of "Male" and "Female" iteration and to display only once. 

            var valueArr = values.map(function(item){ return item.ssmlGender });
                    var isDuplicate = valueArr.some(function(item, idx){ 
                        return valueArr.indexOf(item) != idx 
                    });
                    console.log(isDuplicate);
$('#entries').append('<option value='+(i+1)+'>' + response.result.voices[i].name+ '</option>');


        //Added custom options of "MALE" AND "FEMALE" directly into the voice gender field of HTML to remove the duplicate values.But, it didn't work out. 

        /*if(document.getElementById("gender").value=="FEMALE"){
             if(response.result.voices[i].ssmlGender=="FEMALE")
               {
                 finalLanguages=response.result.voices[i].languageCodes;
                 }                            
               }
        if(document.getElementById("gender").value =="MALE"){
              if(response.result.voices[i].ssmlGender=="MALE")
                   {
                     finalLanguages=response.result.voices[i].languageCodes;
                     }
                  }                 
   $("#languages").append('<option value=' + (i+1)+ '>'+finalLanguages+ '</option>');*/
                          }
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let languageCodes = [
{ languageCodes: ['123'], name: 'es-ES-Standard-A', ssmlGender: 'FEMALE', naturalSampleRateHertz: 2403},
{languageCodes: ['214'], name: 'it-IT-Standard-A', ssmlGender: 'MALE', naturalSampleRateHertz: 21000},
{languageCodes: ['147'], name: 'ja-JP-Standard-A', ssmlGender: 'FEMALE', naturalSampleRateHertz: 3200},
{languageCodes: ['290'], name: 'ko-KR-Standard-A', ssmlGender: 'MALE', naturalSampleRateHertz: 2330},
{languageCodes: ['173'], name: 'en-US-Wavenet-B', ssmlGender: 'FEMALE', naturalSampleRateHertz: 412},
{languageCodes: ['583'], name: 'en-GB-Standard-A', ssmlGender: 'MALE', naturalSampleRateHertz: 8493}
];

// Register Change listeners
function registerEventListeners() {
 document.getElementById('gender').addEventListener('change',  changeVoiceLanguageOption, false);
 document.getElementById('languages').addEventListener('change',  changeVoiceNameOption, false);
}

function changeVoiceNameOption() {
 const valueSelected = document.getElementById('languages').value;
  let entriesElement = document.getElementById('entries');
  entriesElement.innerHTML = '';
  entriesElement.innerHTML += '<option value="" selected>Choose your option</option>'
  
  languageCodes.filter(( item ) => {
    return item.languageCodes.includes(valueSelected);
  }).forEach(( item ) => {
   entriesElement.innerHTML += `<option value="${item.name}"> ${item.name} </option>`
  })
}

function changeVoiceLanguageOption() {
 const valueSelected = document.getElementById('gender').value;
 let languageElement = document.getElementById('languages');
 languageElement.innerHTML = ''; // This is what prevents duplication
 languageElement.innerHTML += '<option value="" selected>Choose your languages</option>'
  
  languageCodes.filter(( item ) => {
    return item.ssmlGender === valueSelected;
  }).forEach(( filteredItems ) => {
   filteredItems.languageCodes.forEach(( languageCode ) => {
     languageElement.innerHTML += `<option value="${languageCode}"> ${languageCode} </option>`
    })
  })
  
  
}

function populateGender() {

let genderElement = document.getElementById('gender');
  let genderObject = {};
  languageCodes.forEach(( item ) => {
    genderObject[item.ssmlGender] = '';
  })
  Object.keys(genderObject).forEach(( item ) => {
    genderElement.innerHTML += `<option value="${item}"> ${item} </option>`
  })
}

registerEventListeners();
populateGender();
```

```html
<div class="row">
                <label>Voice Gender</label>
                <div class="input-field col s12">                    
                    <select id="gender">
                            <option value="" selected>Choose your option</option>                                                     
                            </select>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <label>Voice Language</label>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <select id="languages">
                        <option value="" selected>Choose your languages</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="row">
                <label>Voice Name</label>
                <div class="input-field col s12">                    
                    <select id="entries">
                            <option value="" selected>Choose your option</option>                           
                            </select>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The gender field and name field works good. But, getting the repetition in "language" field - second field. Attaching the screenshot: https://imgur.com/4kT6asd. Also the array contains the "LanguageCodes" as one of its objects as given in the main post imgur link. So, when tried I with other name(ex:responseArray, in order to avoid array element collision) , I was not the getting any elements in the "language" field at all.

Comment: I tried using Set, Object.Key and other methods, I couldn't eliminate the duplication in "languages" code- second field. Is there any other ways to remove the duplication?

Comment: In the code above, I eliminated the duplication by setting innerHTML = ''"  const valueSelected = document.getElementById('gender').value;
 let languageElement = document.getElementById('languages');
 languageElement.innerHTML = '';

Comment: You can paste the code you have, with the data. Let me take a look

Comment: I have create the unique array with the Set function to iterate and stored the values like this: 
`var uniq= [...new Set(langArray)];
   uniq.forEach((item)=>{
   languageElement.innerHTML += `<option value="${item}"> ${item} </option>`
                })`

It worked. But, third field "name" displays only the values corresponding to "language" by including the values of both the genders.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any other way to compare the both the "language" and "gender" field and display the result based on it?

I have re-written the changeVoiceNameOption() like this. I couldn't get the result.

```
        function changeVoiceNameOption() {
genderSelected=document.getElementById('gender').value;
        const languageSelected = document.getElementById('languages').value;
        let entriesElement = document.getElementById('entries');
        entriesElement.innerHTML = '';
        entriesElement.innerHTML += '<option value="" selected>Choose your option</option>'
        var nameArray=[];
    languageCodes.filter(( item ) => {
    return item.ssmlGender.includes(genderSelected);
    }).forEach(( filteredItems ) =>  {filteredItems.languageCodes.forEach(( languageCode ) => {return filteredItems.languageCodes.includes(languageSelected);                        
    })
     }).forEach(( filteredItems ) =>  {
    entriesElement.innerHTML += `<option value="${item.name}"> ${item.name} </option>`
    })
     }
```

Comment: languageSelected.innerHTML = '';   can you do that